# Fill TextBoxes And Combo Boxes On Grid View Cell Content Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, datagridview

I want to fill texboxes and ComboBoxes On  GridView cellContentclick ..How can I do this..

Comment: i think there is no cell content click event in asp.net as in winforms..instead add buttons and change their style so that they look like a normal label..then you can easily handle their click event in row command

Comment: Winforms Do have The grid View cellContentClick Event

Comment: ya i said asp.net doesnot have cellContentClick Event as in winforms

Answer (score 1):

add button to ur gridview and handle its events in gridview rowcommand..